# Trouble with ListView

Tags: android, xml, list, button, view

I have an issue with my Main Activity and a ListView and I absolutly don't understand how it works...

OK ! This is what I want :

Expectation

[image: Expectation display]

It means I need a list of item : TextViews

And OUTSIDE of this list a simple button. I don't want the button to be part of the list.

But here is what I have :

Reality

[image: Reality display]

As you can see, in every child of my list i have my text AND my button : Why ??

My code Main :

```
public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity implements IRemDeck, IRemCard {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

    ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.MainDecksList);
    AdapterDeck adpDeck;
    ArrayList<Deck> myDecks = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i<5;i++){
        myDecks.add(new Deck("Deck " + i));
    }

    adpDeck = new AdapterDeck(this, 0, myDecks);
    listView.setAdapter(adpDeck);

}
```

My Adapter (for the ListView) :

```
public AdapterDeck(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<Deck> decks) {
    super(context, resource, decks);
    this.decks = decks;
    this.context = context;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return decks.size();
}

@Override
public Deck getItem(int pos) {
    return decks.get(pos);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int pos) {
    return 0;
    //just return 0 if your list items do not have an Id variable.
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_menu, null);
    }

    //Handle TextView and display string from your list
    TextView listItemText = view.findViewById(R.id.MainDeckNom);
    listItemText.setText(decks.get(position).getNom());


    return view;
}
```

The XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activities.MainMenu">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/MainDeckNom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/MainDecksList"
    android:layout_width="363dp"
    android:layout_height="426dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/MainDecksList" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

If someone could explain to me how to solve my problem (and how it works eventually) I would be very grateful !

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

listview has to have its own layout, so you need to create a new layout that just contains listview and in `getView()` method use it as a row of your listView

1- create a new `row_listview.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activities.MainMenu">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/MainDeckNom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

2-Change this line

```
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_menu, null);
```

to

```
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_listview, null);
```

Comment: Thanks ! I've finally understood how it works ! :) 
I like your method with several XML !

Comment: Happy Coding.  Use RecyclerView instead of listView, it's better.  Read article about the difference.

Comment: Ok I'll investigate 
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter's getView() method, you have to design a child_view layout. The layout which you return will be show in every item of the list. Because you're returning main_activity_layout so every your item would show the mainAcitivy, which contains a button. Solution is create new layout with your own design and replace it with R.layout.main_acitivity_layout. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You should not use R.layout.activity_main_menu in getView, because getView returns a line of the list which you don't want to have a button.

So, you have a separate layout activity_main_men specified as Content view for the activity which does not have TextView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activities.MainMenu">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/MainDecksList"
    android:layout_width="363dp"
    android:layout_height="426dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/MainDecksList" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The in getView instead of

view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_menu, null);

you just place:

```
view = new TextView()
view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment ! I understand now how it works. 
Even if you method works I prefer the Momen Zaqout one :) 
Thanks again